# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jspdf-autoTable'

Tags: angular, jspdf-autotable

Getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jspdf-autoTable'  error even though it was there in node_modules folder. I'm using below versions

"jspdf": "2.5.1",
"jspdf-autotable": "3.6.0" and on angular 8.x

I have added these in tsconfig.json

"types": ["node","jspdf-autotable"] and in angular.json file added these under scripts section.

```
"node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js",
"node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
```

But none seems to be working. Let me know, if anyone have any suggestions on this. Thanks.